# How can we compare two Matrices in power BI?

Tags: matrix, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals, daxstudio

I'm seeking assistance in resolving the following query. I have monthly Sales data in Excel, and I'm comparing two different month values using Pivot tables in Excel. I've accomplished this by creating two Pivot tables and then finding the difference using a formula.

Now, I'm looking to achieve the same in Power BI. In Power BI, I've already created two matrices that display the same columns and rows, and we can select any month based on a month slicer. My question is, how can I compare or find the difference between these two matrices in Power BI?

Thank you for your help. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmovW.jpg)

I need to find the differences betwenen any two matrices in Power BI

Comment: What's the change between the the two tables? You are going to need to create potentially three measures. A measure for each table with what ever the filter is. The third measure will simply be [measure 1] - [measure 2]. Share a little more on your data model, screen shots, or best yet share a sample PBIX (via a public share link).

Comment: 1. What's the change between the the two tables? The change between the two tables is like I have I have sales data for every month from 2022 to Oct 2023 and In excel I have created two separate Pivot tables just for comparing any motnh values with the other pivots same thing i want in Power BI.

Comment: Power BI doesn't have a feature where you can compare two visuals (matrices).
Options available include creating measures - if you want to compare any month with another month then you'll need two Date tables (one for each filter/slicer). If you only want to compare with the previous month or year, then this is possible with just one date table - see: https://radacad.com/month-over-month-calculation-in-power-bi-using-dax. Another option is to use a waterfall visual https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-waterfall-charts?tabs=powerbi-desktop